# Python using jupyter

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

I have a create a function called `over_kmph_limit` which takes two parameters:

- `mph_speed`(representing the speed of a car in miles per hour)
- `kmph_limit`(representing the speed limit in kilometres per hour)

The function should return `True` if the car is exceeding the speed limit, and `False` otherwise. Input values will always be single positive numerical values.

Here is what I tried:

```
def over_kmph_limit(mph_speed, kmph_limit):
    for x, y in range(mph_speed, kmph_limit):
        convert = x * 1.61
        if convert > y:
            Print('True')
        else:
            Print('False')
    return
```

I'm new to programming, so this might not be good.
Another try was like below

```
def over_kmph_limit(mph_speed):
    for i in range(mph_speed):
        Convert = i * 1.61


    return Convert
```

One of the test cases will be like

```
over_kmph_limit(30, 40)
```

Comment: 1- you don't need a loop, 2- `Print` is `print`, 3- no need to `return` if you `print`

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) -- we don't just do your homework for you; you're expected to ask about a _specific problem_ with your _existing code_, factoring out the parts of the assignment that aren't related to the technical problem that prevents you from completing it yourself. So -- don't just show your attempts and hope we can infer where you're stuck, but also describe what specific misunderstanding you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. The specific misunderstanding for me would be  trying to assign x & y to the parameters above (mph_speed, kmph_limit).

Comment: Thank you Charles for helping me realise a mistake of mine of just asking for the answer I realised I was over complicating and managed to get an answer

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up a lot of things here. You are a beginner and you must invest your time in learning the basics of coding and then try yourself a lot.

What you have to achieve can be done simply like below

```
def over_kmph_limit(mph_speed, kmph_limit):
    # return if miles converted to km, is greater than the km limit
    return mph_speed*1.61 > kmph_limit
```

Comment: I was able to look at the problem again after a comment helped me realise that I am just asking for the answer rather than actually understanding where the problem is and managed to get it

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you solving the problem1

Comment: I have bookmarked the answer and will make sure to accept when i reach 15 reputations thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
def over_kmph_limit(mph_speed, kmph_limit):
    convert = mph_speed * 1.61
    if convert > kmph_limit:
        return True
    return False
```

Thanks for the help (not sarcasm)

Comment: The statements in the `over_kmph_limit()` block must indent with 2 or 4 spaces. Indention is very important in Python.